# Get JSON appended items in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

I am trying to get a JSON appended item to show on click in another div.

For example -

```
$.getJSON("URLHERE", function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
     $(".mydiv").append( "<div class='newdiv'>" + field.name + "," + field.event +  "</div>");
  });
```

this gets my JSON information and adds it to .mydiv for each item.

Now - I am trying to get this information again, to show in another div, but only for the selected item. I have tried to add a click function to show the JSON information but only for the selected, but with no luck.

```
$('.mydiv').click(function() {
         $(".seconddiv").append(field.name);
 });
```

If anyone can put me on the right track it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT

My HTML

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="mydiv">
               <h1>...</h1>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="seconddiv">
               <h1>...</h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

EDIT 2

```
$.getJSON("URLHERE", function(result){
       $.each(result, function(i, field){
         $(".mydiv").append( "<div class='newdiv'>" + field.name + "," + field.event +  "</div>");

         $(document).on('click', 'div.newdiv', function(){
           $('div.seconddiv').append( $(this).html() );
        });

      });
```

EDIT 3:

So, This is working, BUT it is looping through each JSON and pulling the name through, I basically need only this name.

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("URLHERE", function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
          $(".mydiv").append( "<div class='newdiv'>" + field.name + "," + field.event +  "</div>");
       });


        $('.newdiv').click(function() {
         $(".seconddiv").append(field.name); // HOW TO ONLY GET THIS FIELD NAME, NOT FOR EACH JSON ITEM
      });

     });
   });
```

Comment: share your html please

Comment: You have not posted any HTML. I do believe that `<div class="mydiv"></div>` is included in your HTML. Can you please verify that?

Comment: Added HTML to the OP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionality is a little unclear but here is a solution for when you want to display info and on click display only a selected name in a different div. I would recommend storing JSON attributes as data elements on newly created divs which can be later easily retrieved via a simple click handler.

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7961d87z/

And just the code

HTML

```
<!-- placeholder for your data -->
    <div class="mydiv"></div>
<!-- placeholder for click events -->
    <div class="result"></div>
```

Javascript

```
//fake data
    result= [{name:"item1", event: "something"}, {name:"item2", event: "someevent"}];


     $.each(result, function(i, field){
     //create an element and append data attribute to the element - in this case field name
     el = $("<div class='newdiv'>" + field.name + "," + field.event +  "</div>").data("name", field.name);
     //append element to DOM
        $(".mydiv").append( el );
        })
      //define a click handler for all new elements to display data in a div
        $(".mydiv").on( "click", ".newdiv", function() {
      $(".result").text( $( this ).data("name") );
    });
```

Comment: Hi Michal,
This works well! Only question - Is there a way to add this text to the new div, until I want to remove it.

For example - I clicked on the first name and event, and it displays the name in a new div. Then I click another one and it sits underneath it instead of replacing it? And maybe like clicking on it again to remove it from this div? Sorry for the additional work, I will accept the answer as Its what my OP asked!!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't in your DOM element on load as you append it. What you want to do is actually manage the clicked element:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'div.mydiv', function(){
    
});
```

You must also remember, that you can't access the `JSON` outside of your `$.getJSON()` call.

---

#### Edit

To only show your clicked one, you'll need to fetch the `.html()` and append that to the new `div`. That looks something like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'div.mydiv', function(){
    jQuery('div.mynewdiv').append( jQuery(this).html() );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm such a beginner.

jQuery(document).on('click', 'div.mydiv', function(){
$(".seconddiv").append(field.name);
});

This should now display the name for the clicked item only?

Comment: Yes it should, but you need to understand that you **can't** access `field.name` if this isn't inside your `$.getJSON()`. Unless you want to show the already created div inside another div right?

Comment: Sorry, 
I want to show the field.name but only for the data clicked.

So I have 9 outputs, when i click one of them, I only want the selected name to show in a completely seperate div

Comment: I have edited my OP with the attempted code. It is now pulling all the information through, but doing it X amount of times, so if theres 9 bits of information it is doing it 9 times. Also, is there a way to only get one bit of data, so instead of pulling through the name and the event, to only pull the name?

Comment: Edited the op. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This creates **HTML** for element having class `mydiv`

```
$.getJSON("URLHERE", function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
     $(".mydiv").append( "<div class='newdiv'>" + field.name + "," + field.event +  "</div>");
  });
```

Use this to append to `.seconddiv` the information you want

```
$(document).on('click','.newdiv',function() {
     $(".seconddiv").append($(this).html()); // fieldName,fieldEvent
});
```